# MySql hierarchical query

Tags: mysql, recursion, hierarchical

I have Organizations table:

```
Id  Name  ParentId
------------------
 1  Org1         5
 2  Org2         5
 3  Org3         4
 4  Depart2      6
 5  Depart1      6
 6  Company   null
```

What I would like to achieve is query which returns table
with belonging of each organization to higher order organization units up in hierarchy tree:

```
Id    BelongsToOrgId
1     1                  Org1 is part of Org1
1     5                  Org1 is part of Depart1  
1     6                  Org1 is part of Company
2     2                  Org2 is part of Org2
2     5                  Org2 is part of Depart1
2     6                  Org2 is part of Company
3     3                  Org3 is part of Org3
3     4                  Org3 is part of Depart2
3     6                  Org3 is part of Company
4     4                  Depart2 is part of Depart2 
4     6                  Depart2 is part of Company 
5     5                  Depart1 is part of Depart1  
5     6                  Depart1 is part of Company
6     6                  Company is part of Company
```

Best Regards,
Piotr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT Id, Name, id BelongsToOrgId, Name UpperName
         FROM Organizations 
       UNION ALL
         SELECT Organizations.Id, Organizations.Name, cte.BelongsToOrgId, cte.Name
         FROM Organizations 
         JOIN cte ON Organizations.ParentId = cte.Id )
SELECT Id, BelongsToOrgId, CONCAT(Name, ' is part of ', UpperName) Relation
FROM cte
ORDER BY Id, BelongsToOrgId;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa0fe3e980656cbab0629392492c4f2c)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Akina,

We are almost there, one fix:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT Id, Name, id BelongsToOrgId, Name UpperName
         FROM Organizations 
       UNION ALL
         SELECT Organizations.Id, Organizations.Name, cte.BelongsToOrgId, cte.UpperName
         FROM Organizations 
         JOIN cte ON Organizations.ParentId = cte.Id )
SELECT Id, BelongsToOrgId, CONCAT(Name, ' is part of ', UpperName) Relation
FROM cte
ORDER BY Id, BelongsToOrgId;
```

It is cte.UpperName and not cte.Name in line 5